# Go (golang) retrieving results from last statement in multiple statement mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, go

I am calling a `mysql 5.7` stored procedure which has two statements with `go mysql driver`.

First statement only assigns values to variables from database

E.g: `select @location=location, @stat=stat from user where ...`

Second statement

```
Select id, name, ... from user where ..
```

I have no control over the procedure and need to use the results of the second statement.

How can I access the results in go?

Comment: You can use `Scan()` after firing query in database with function `QueryRow()` .

Comment: I am not sure how that can be used to solve this particular case.  An example would help.

Comment: How do you execute your sql query ?